# OpenEdge 11.3 Application Migration

Tags: database-migration, progress-4gl, openedge, code-migration

We have an application with 10 millions lines of code in 4GL(Progress) and a database also OpenEdge with 300 Tables. My Boss says we should migrate it to a new Programming language and a new Database Management system.
My questions are:

1. Do you think we should migrate it? Do you think Progress has a "future"?
2. If we should migrate it, how, are there any tools? Or should we begin with programming from scratch?

Thank you for the help.
Ablo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your boss has access to an unlimited budget, endless user patience and a thirst for frustration and agony you should not waste any time thinking about rewrites.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Yes, Progress has a future.  They probably will never be as sexy an option as Microsoft or Oracle or whatever the cool kids are using this week.  But they have been around for 30 years and they will still be here when you and your boss retire.

There are those who will rain down scorn on Progress because it isn't X or it doesn't have Y.  Maybe they can rewrite your 10 million lines of code next weekend and prove just how right they are.  I would not, however, pay them for those efforts until after the user acceptance tests are passed and the implementation is completed.

Comment: That voice in the back of my head finally clicked and remembered to link Joel's excellent essay on why "rewrite" is such a bad idea.

Comment: but you did not answer the question: does Progress have a future? perhaps the company will be bankrupt? its also very very hard to find Progress Developer!!

Comment: Actually I did.  I said "Yes, Progress has a future...".  Which is very true.  They have plenty of money in the bank, a strong balance sheet and an excellent track record as a going concern.

Comment: It is not all that hard to find Progress developers.  Unless you really mean "Progress developers willing to work for peanuts".  In which case, yes it is hard.  And if you find any of those there is probably a good reason why they are so cheap.  It is also very easy to train good programmers to use Progress.  But that's not what you were asking about....

Comment: Joel-on-software's remark about "not rewriting" is spot on, but you need to be careful about what "rewrite" means.  Joel's "rewrite" means *by hand* because this leads to disaster by a variety of failure modes which his article describes.  Mechanical "rewrites" or migrations can do such conversions *and* avoid those failure modes.   Now the question for management is, "convert to achieve (some effect)"  or not, and quantifying the costs and payoffs for each.   Each organization will arrive at a different answer because of circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years later (the original post being from 2014 and the answers being from 2014 to 2015) :

The post, which has gotten the most votes is argumenting basically two fold :

a. Progress (Openedge) has been around for a long time and is not going anywhere soon

b. Unless your boss has access to an unlimited budget, endless user patience and a thirst for frustration and agony you should not waste any time thinking about rewrites: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

With regard to a:

Yes, the Progress OpenEdge Stack  is still around. But from my experience the difficulty to find experienced and skilled Openedge has gotten even more difficult.

But also an important factor here, which i think has evolved to much greater importance, since this discussion started:

The available Open Source Stacks for application development have gotten by factors better, both in terms of out-of-box functionality and quality and have decisively moved in direction of RAD.

I am thinking for instance of Spring Boot, but not only, see https://stackshare.io/spring-boot/alternatives. In the Java realm Spring Boot is certainly unique.  Also for the development of rich Webui's  many very valid options have emerged, which certainly are addressing RAD requirements, just some "arbitrary" examples https://vaadin.com for Java, but also https://www.polymer-project.org  for Javascript, which are interestingly converging both with https://vaadin.com/flow.

Many of the available stacks are still evolving strongly, but all have making life easier for the developer as strong driver.  Also in terms of architectures you will find a convergence of many of this stacks with regard basic building blocks and principles: Separation of Interfaces from Implementation, REST API's for remote communication, Object Relational Mapping Technologies, NoSql / Json approaches etc etc.

So yes the Open Source Stack are getting very efficient in terms of Development. And what must also be mentioned, that the scope of these stacks do not stop with development:  Deployment, Operational Aspects and naturally also Testing are a strong ,which in the end also make the developers life easier.

Generally one can say the a well choosen Mix and Match of Open Source Stacks have a very strong value proposition, also on the background of RAD requirements, which a proprietary Stack, will have in the long run difficulty to match - at least from my point of view.

With regard to b:

Interestingly enough i was just recently with a customer, who is looking to do exactly this: rewrite their application. The irony: they are migrating from Progress to Progress OpenEdge, with several additional Open Edge compliant Tools. The reason two fold: Their code is getting very difficult to maintain and would refactoring in order to address requirements coming from Web Frontends. Also interesting, they are not finding enough qualified developers.

Basically: Code is sound and lives , when it can be refactored and when it can evolve with new requirements. Unfortunately there many examples - at least from my experience - to contrary.

Additionally End-of-Lifecyle of Software can force a company, to "rewrite" at least layers of their software.  And this doesn't necessarily have to bad and impossible. I worked on a Project, which migrated over 300 Oracle Forms forms to a Java based UI within less then two years. This migration from a 2 tier to a 3 tier architecture actually positioned the company to evolve their architecture to address the needs of Web Ui's. So actually in the end this "rewrite" and a strong return of value also from the business perspective.

So to cut a (very;-)) long story short:

One way or another, it is easy to go wrong with generalizations.

Answer (score 0):

You need not begin programming from scratch. There is help available online and yes, you can contact Progress Technical Support if you find difficulties. Generally, ABL code from previous version should work with only little changes. Here are few things that you need to do in order to migrate your application:

Backup databases
Backup source code and .r files
Truncate DB bi files
Convert your databases
Recompile ABL code and test

http://knowledgebase.progress.com articles will help you in this. If you are migrating from some older versions like 9, you can find a good set of new features. You can try them but only after you are done with your conversion.

If you are migrating from 32-bit to 64-bit and if you are using 32-bit libraries, you need to replace them with 64-bit

Comment: but you did not answer the question: does Progress have a future? perhaps the company will be bankrupt? its also very very hard to find Progress Developer!!

Comment: @SW-Entwickler, I agree with Tim and Tom in this case. Progress has a future. Moreover, Progress is at least thinking of future and updating their products.

Answer (score 0):

The first question I'd come back with is 'why'? If the **application** is not measuring up that's one thing, and the question needs to be looked at from that perspective.

If the perception is that Progress is somehow a "lesser" application development and operating environment, and the desire is *only* to move to a different development and operating environment - you'll end up with a lot of resources in time, effort, and money invested - not to mention the opportunity cost - and for what? To run on a different database platform? Will migrating result in a lower TCO? Faster development turn-around time? Quicker time to market? What's expected advantage in moving from Progress, and how long will it take to recover the migration cost - if ever?

Somewhere out there is a company who had similar thoughts and tried to move off of Progress and the ABL. The effort failed to meet their target performance and functionality metrics, so they eventually gave up on the migration, threw in the towel, and stayed with Progress - after spending $25M on the project.

Can your company afford that kind of risk / reward ratio?

Comment: but you did not answer the question: does Progress have a future? perhaps the company will be bankrupt? its also very very hard to find Progress Developer!!

Comment: Progress has a future. They're in no danger of bankruptcy, and the language isn't that hard to learn, with lots of resources available to get someone new going.

Answer (score 0):

Progress (Openedge) has been around for a long time and is not going anywhere soon.  And rewriting 10 Million lines of code in any language just to use the current flavor of the month would never be worth it unless your current application is not doing what you need. Even then bringing it up to current needs would normally be a better solution.

If you need to migrate your current application to the latest version of Openedge (Progress) you would normally just make a copy of your database(s) and convert it/them to the new version of Openedge and compile your your code against the new databases and shake the bugs out.  You may have some keyword issues, but this is usually pretty minor.

If you need help with programming I would suggest contacting Progress Software and attending the yearly trade show or going to https://community.progress.com/ and asking/looking for local user groups. The local user groups would be a stellar place to find local programming talent.

Hope this helps.....